# Sorting Collection of objects

Tags: c#

I have this class:

```
public class Myclass
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}
```

And Collection:

```
Collection<Myclass> myCollection = new Collection<Myclass>();
```

How i can sort this collection by id in place????

Comment: Do you actually need to use `Collection<T>` ? Can you switch to `List<T>` instead ?

Comment: how they differ? List<T> are better?

Comment: Because `Collection<T>` doesn't have the `Sort()` method, while `List<T>` does...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your class implment IComparable, and define

```
int CompareTo(MyClass other)
{
    return Id.compareTo(other.Id);
}
```

Then any standard sort functions can be used.

Answer (score 3):

Linq is the most straightforward way

```
var sorted = (from my in myCollection orderby my.id select my).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Do like this with `lambda expreesion`:

```
myCollection.Sort((a,b) => a.id.CompareTo(b.id));
```

If your class implements `IComparable<T>` in following way:

```
public class Myclass : IComparable<Myclass> {
   public int id;
   public string name; 

    public int CompareTo(Myclass myClass) {
        return id.CompareTo(myClass.id);
    }
}
```

Then, you directly can call `Sort()` method:

```
   myCollection.Sort();
```

I have used myCollection as for you but indeed it do not have `Sort()` method....Instead, you can make your `myCollection` to List so that list can use `Sort()` method.

Comment: @AlexF: Actually this answer is not completely accurate. If you use the first line you don't need to change `MyClass` (i.e. no need to implement `IComparable<>`). Instead, if `MyClass` implements `IComparable<>` like in the last code snippet, you can use directly `myCollection.Sort()` without any lambda expression. Finally, `Collection<>` has no method `Sort()`; `List<>` does.

Comment: @digEmAll: you are right! I decided to use `List<T>` in my project, thanks to you! I do not know why, but I thought that the collection is better than a list, but it turned out the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Collection myCl= new Collection();

```
var res = myCl.OrderBy(mc=>mc.Id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Collection<Myclass> ss = new Collection<Myclass>();
var ordered=ss.OrderBy(s => s.id).ToList();
```

now order will be a list of MyClass object order by the ID

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use List instead of Collection. For sorting you can use Linq operator OrderBy.

```
List<Myclass> items = new List<Myclass>();
// Add items here
items=items.OrderBy(item=>item.Id).ToList();
```